# How can I move logo to top center of the page over a video background

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm struggling to get my logo to sit top middle of the page and to be responsive. I currently have it in a container div where it sits next to two other divs navOne and navTwo. Although I want it to be more independent and responsive at the top middle of the page.

This is my component:

```
    import React from "react";
// import landingVideo from "../assets/landing.mp4";
// import landingVideo2 from "../assets/landing.mp4";
import landingVideo3 from "../assets/landing3.mp4";
import ellena from "../assets/ellena.png";
import "./landing.css";

function Landing() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="heading">{/* <img src={ellena} alt="" /> */}</div>
      <div className="overlay"></div>

      <video src={landingVideo3} autoPlay loop muted />

      <div className="container">
        <div className="title">
          <img className="logo" src={ellena} alt="" />
        </div>

        <div className="navOne">
          <h1>Commercial</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="navTwo">
          <h1>Weddings</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Landing;
```

And my css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.title {
  display: block;
}
.logo {
  max-width: 40%;
  max-height: 40%;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 5px;
}

.navOne {
  border: 1px white solid;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.44em;
  padding-right: calc(1.44em - 0.2em);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.44em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: futura-pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14px;

  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Inria Serif", serif;
}
.navTwo {
  border: 1px white solid;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.44em;
  padding-right: calc(1.44em - 0.2em);
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 1.44em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: futura-pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14px;

  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-family: "Inria Serif", serif;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: rgba(252, 226, 160, 0.2); */
}
```

Should I remove the logo from the container div?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share in codesand box

Comment: @Lucifer let me know if this is correct https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cache-8byelx?file=/static/js/main.4057da24.js

Comment: your react code is encrypted